# Xamarin Forms-Identify if device is locked in portrait mode

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, device-orientation

I have created a Xamarin Forms App.The user navigates from View A to View B.The requirement of View B is that it should be in Landscape mode only irrespective of whether the device orientation is locked or not.I am able to achieve this using Custom renderer

```
   protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        ((MainActivity)Context).RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
    }
```

When the user navigates back to View A, I want the view to rotate to its respective orientation based on whether the device is in locked portrait state or Auto rotate state.How to achieve this behavior?
How to check if the device is locked in portrait mode?

Comment: What do you mean by " I want the view to rotate to its respective orientation based on whether the device is in locked portrait state or Auto rotate state"

Comment: For iPads/Tablets?

Comment: @G.hakim If the device is locked in portrait mode then it should display in Portrait mode only.If the device is in Auto rotate mode then it should either display in landscape or portrait based on device orientation.It should work for both iOS and Android.

Comment: @jamesfdearborn Both Android phones and tablets and iOS iphones and ipads.

Comment: Then do one thing when you get back to that page set the Screen Orientation to User

Comment: @G.hakim Yes I was able to achieve the desired result in Android using  MainActivity.Instance.RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.FullUser; How to do it in iOS?Please help

Comment: putting it as an answer in 5mins, just change the condition as per your need

Answer (score 0):

If user is on View B and is in Portrait mode, display a message informing them to use Landscape mode.

As far as I know the app, at least within Xamarin, cannot change user's device orientation for specific pages.